# Hauppauge 1800 cannot output to tv?

Tags: windows-vista, tv, dvr, hauppauge

I just got my new card hauppauge 1800 WinTv and all work fine in my second screen. THe problem is that the only way I have found to display the Tv show to the Television Screen is by using the S-Video Output of my ATI Card and that simply project the stuff from my second screen (that has Window Media Center) to it.

Is there a way that I can still use my second screen and be able to output from my hauppauge 1800 to the Television? I have tried to take the S-Video cable and connect it to the hauppauge 1800 but nothing is outputed?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hauppauge 1800 does not produce any video output - the S-Video connector is for input only. You will need a video card that has two completely independent outputs.

Comment: Is there a way without having to use the second screen?